# send message more than once in wa web js

Tags: node.js

I have an issue with my WhatsApp Web JavaScript application. I inserted my QR code into an Express template. It works fine initially, but it encounters a problem when I refresh the page and change the QR code. Instead, it ends up sending multiple times depending on how many times I refresh it.

here is my code that i made

```
  app.get('/qrcode', async (req, res) => {
    let qrRendered = false;
  
    client.on('qr', qr => {
      if (!qrRendered) {
        const textToEncode = qr;
        QRCode.generate(textToEncode, { small: true, width: 8000 }, (qrcode) => {
          res.render("qrcode", {
            qr: qrcode
          });
          qrRendered = true; 
        });
      }
    });
  
    client.once('ready', async () => {
      console.log('Client is ready!');
  
      console.log('Sending messages...');
      var nomer_telephone = ["+6281932240030", "+6281932240030","+6281932240030"];
      var textId = `Assalamualaikum Wr.wb`; 
  
      for (var nomor = 0; nomor < nomer_telephone.length; nomor++) {
        var chatId = nomer_telephone[nomor].substring(1) + "@c.us"; 
        client.sendMessage(chatId, textId);
      }
    });

    client.initialize();
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

this is html code for express js

```
    <pre><%= qr %></pre>
```

Now, when I refresh twice and change the QR code twice as well, for example, it will send twice to those three numbers that I've put into an array.

when i refresh and change qr twice

```
Client is ready!
Sending messages...
Client is ready!
Sending messages...
```

When refreshed twice, it should still only execute once.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is due to the fact that every time you access the `/qrcode` route, you are adding new `qr` and `ready` event listeners. These listeners accumulate with each request, causing the messages to be sent multiple times.

To resolve this issue, you need to move the event listener registration outside of the route handler. One way to do this is to register the event listeners outside the route handler, and then use flags to determine whether the QR code has been rendered and whether the messages have been sent.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```js
let qrRendered = false;
let messagesSent = false;

client.on('qr', qr => {
  if (!qrRendered) {
    const textToEncode = qr;
    QRCode.generate(textToEncode, { small: true, width: 8000 }, (qrcode) => {
      qrRendered = true;
      // Render the QR code only once
      app.get('/qrcode', (req, res) => {
        res.render("qrcode", {
          qr: qrcode
        });
      });
    });
  }
});

client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log('Client is ready!');

  // Send messages only once
  if (!messagesSent) {
    console.log('Sending messages...');
    var nomer_telephone = ["+6281932240030", "+6281932240030", "+6281932240030"];
    var textId = `Assalamualaikum Wr.wb`;

    for (var nomor = 0; nomor < nomer_telephone.length; nomor++) {
      var chatId = nomer_telephone[nomor].substring(1) + "@c.us";
      client.sendMessage(chatId, textId);
    }

    messagesSent = true;
  }
});

client.initialize();

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This way, the event listeners are only added once, and the flags `qrRendered` and `messagesSent` ensure that the rendering of the QR code and sending of messages happen only once during the application's lifetime.